# Customize navigation bar by adding two labels instead of title in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add two labels in the place where the title is shown in navigation bar, but I am struggling to do so. It would be very nice if I could achieve this with storyboard but as I can see I cannot do it.

As I have seen I need to use navigationItem but I do not know how exactly to do that. If anyone have any example or if anyone could explain me more specifically how to do so would be wonderful.

And I need to mention that I am completely unfamiliar with Obj-C, so any help would need to be in Swift.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do it from the storyboard, but if you want to add two title labels, you can do the following in the `viewDidLoad()` method of the view controller for which you want the two titles:

```
if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
    let firstFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navigationBar.frame.width/2, height: navigationBar.frame.height)
    let secondFrame = CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2, y: 0, width: navigationBar.frame.width/2, height: navigationBar.frame.height)

    let firstLabel = UILabel(frame: firstFrame)
    firstLabel.text = "First"

    let secondLabel = UILabel(frame: secondFrame)
    secondLabel.text = "Second"

    navigationBar.addSubview(firstLabel)
    navigationBar.addSubview(secondLabel)
}
```

In this way you can add as many subviews as you want to the navigation bar

Comment: if u please can help me with an additional question. How can I add constrains to these labels so they will be placed center horizontally and one underneath the other one

Comment: @vdawg labels are aligning back to back...plz tell us how to align labels one above another

Comment: @Bevan you can just change the firstFrame' and secondFrame properties to adjust the frames of the labels
    let firstFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: navigationBar.frame.width, height: navigationBar.frame.height/2)
    let secondFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: navigationBar.frame.height/2, width: navigationBar.frame.width, height: navigationBar.frame.height/2)

Comment: In my case Center Align also did the trick  : 


firstLabel.textAlignment = .Center

Answer (score 22):

Here's an implementation that uses a stack view instead, which also gives you some versatility with layout of the labels:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var titleStackView: UIStackView = {
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel.text = "Title"
        let subtitleLabel = UILabel()
        subtitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
        subtitleLabel.text = "Subtitle"
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, subtitleLabel])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        return stackView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.titleView = titleStackView
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        if view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
            titleStackView.axis = .vertical
            titleStackView.spacing = UIStackView.spacingUseDefault
        } else {
            titleStackView.axis = .horizontal
            titleStackView.spacing = 20.0
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Demonstrates using a stack view to create a custom navigation item's title view]